# Mysql - Select from one query multiple Alias

Tags: mysql, alias

I have a problem.

I'm using this query:

```
...
(SELECT TXTVALUE
FROM table 
WHERE
    EXTID = 2
)AS A,

(SELECT TXTVALUE 
FROM table 
WHERE
    EXTID = 4
)AS B
...
```

So in the end my goal is just call one's the query and create one alias per condition.
Right now I have several queries(like this example up) calling the same table and I just need to have one different alias depending the condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can you tell us what is the greater goal that you want to achieve ? i order to get the big picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` for this:

```
SELECT TXTVALUE, EXTID 
FROM table 
WHERE  EXTID = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT TXTVALUE, ECTID
FROM table 
WHERE  EXTID = 4
UNION ALL
....
```

This will let you specify a column, so that it have a different values depending on the condition under the same column.

```
SELECT TXTVALUE, EXTID AS 'Types' -- For example
FROM table 
WHERE  EXTID = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT TXTVALUE, ECTID
FROM table 
WHERE  EXTID = 4
UNION ALL
....
```